# Javascript check if range overlaps

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript- objects:

```
function checkTimeOverlapping() {

        var scheduleIntervalContainerWrappers = [];

        var scheduleIntervalContainerWrapper1 = {};
        scheduleIntervalContainerWrapper1.start = '08:00';
        scheduleIntervalContainerWrapper1.end = '10:00';
        scheduleIntervalContainerWrappers.push(scheduleIntervalContainerWrapper1);

        var scheduleIntervalContainerWrapper2 = {};
        scheduleIntervalContainerWrapper2.start = '09:00';
        scheduleIntervalContainerWrapper2.end = '14:00';
        scheduleIntervalContainerWrappers.push(scheduleIntervalContainerWrapper2);

         ...

        alert(scheduleIntervalContainerWrappers);   
    }
```

and I will check if the **scheduleIntervalContainerWrapper** overlap with start and end time. 
Is there a possibility to do this in pure js?

Comment: `scheduleIntervalContainerWrapper1.end` is missing...

Comment: Since JavaScript is a Turing complete language, I would think yes.

Comment: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201310/range_overlap_in_two_compares.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proposal with some test cases. With conversion to minutes.

```js
function overlapping(a, b) {
    function getMinutes(s) {
        var p = s.split(':').map(Number);
        return p[0] * 60 + p[1];
    }
    return getMinutes(a.end) > getMinutes(b.start) && getMinutes(b.end) > getMinutes(a.start);
}

document.write(overlapping({ start: '00:00', end: '00:00' }, { start: '00:00', end: '00:00' }) + '<br>');
document.write(overlapping({ start: '00:00', end: '02:00' }, { start: '00:00', end: '02:00' }) + '<br>');
document.write(overlapping({ start: '00:00', end: '10:00' }, { start: '02:00', end: '10:00' }) + '<br>');
document.write(overlapping({ start: '20:00', end: '22:00' }, { start: '20:00', end: '21:00' }) + '<br>');
document.write(overlapping({ start: '20:00', end: '21:00' }, { start: '20:00', end: '22:00' }) + '<br>');
document.write(overlapping({ start: '02:00', end: '03:00' }, { start: '01:00', end: '02:30' }) + '<br>');
document.write(overlapping({ start: '00:00', end: '05:00' }, { start: '05:00', end: '10:00' }) + '<br>');
document.write(overlapping({ start: '10:00', end: '15:00' }, { start: '00:00', end: '08:00' }) + '<br>');
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I need - but for n times. So I have to split my n times in to couples and iterate through? Or is there a better way to do it? Thanks a lot

Comment: yes, you have to iterate over. another solution is thinkable, but requires more overhead.

Comment: do you have any hint how I can do this. Splitting my array e.g. of 6 intervals - each combination - makes many effort and is difficult ti made? Thanks a lot

Comment: two loops one from 0 ... n -1 and the other from i ... n

Comment: I would need help, I have tried but failed. My Js knowledge is to bad

Comment: in this case, you could ask a new question with the data you have.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is just convert your hours/mn to 'minutes of the day' and perform all the necessary check :

```
 // convert all your value like this
 var tab =  scheduleIntervalContainerWrapper1.start.split(',');
 if(tab[1] < tab[0]){
    tab[1]+=24*60;// overlapping on a day
 }
 var startMinuteOfTheDay = parseInt(tab[0]*60)+parseInt(tab[1]);
```

About the checks : if you're sure the end1 is always greater than start1 and same for second interval.

```
if((start1 > start2 && start1 < end2) || (end1 < end2 && end1 > start2))
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to handle various cases for overlap i.e.

```
start1 ... end1
start2 ... end2

start1 ............. end1
        start2 ..... end2

start1 ............. end1
start2 ..... end2

start1 ... end1
start2 ........... end2

      start1 ... end1
start2 ......... end2

start1 .......... end1
       start2 ........... end2

       start1 .......... end1
start2 ......... end2
```

You can write down the corresponding cases with `if-then-else`.